# In memory buffer with write() and readline()

Tags: python, buffer, readline

I want to store byte data I’m getting into an in memory buffer. I want to then call a method to receive a line from that buffer, similar to readline(), whilst also removing it from the buffer.

Is there an existing python class that I can use that will achieve this?

I’m staying away from decoding the bytes to a string, and string.split(‘\n’) because it can fail if an escaped new line character exists in that string etc. The readline() is more complicated and capable than a split().

I’ve looked at io.BytesIO but it doesn’t satisfy all my requirements, mainly because the readline() method doesn’t remove the returned line from the buffer.

Comment: Then you need a FIFO (First In First Out) like https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: Why does it matter if io.BytesIO it removes it or not? As far as your code is concerned it's gone because the read pointer has moved past it. And what do you think readline() can do that spilt('\n') can't?

Comment: @President That’s not good programming. You don’t want a buffer that’s quietly growing in size. Unless it’s garbage collected, even though it’s being used?

Comment: Why would the buffer be growing? You put bytes in at the beginning and then you read from it.

Comment: Why is the buffer quietly growing in size?

Comment: If you read() from a BytesIO buffer, it won’t remove the data you read, it will remain in the buffer.